# VSCode formatting using "Laravel Blade Formatter" and "PHP Intelephense"

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I use "PHP Intelephense" to format Controller file and "Laravel Blade Formatter" for Blade file and I find it extremely uninteresting to switch between these formatters back and forth.

Is there any efficient way to switch between these two formatter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to VSCode settings JSON file `settings.json` and do **language specific settings**

```json
"[php]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
},
"[blade]":{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "shufo.vscode-blade-formatter"
}
```

**Laravel Blade Formatter** Already run only for **Blade** and **JSON** [image]

Comment: I should have asked it earlier. Google search didn't help much.