# VScode - Laravel blade syntax - highlighting matching tags/pairs

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Looking for a **setting** or an **extension preferably** in **VSCode** to **highlight blade syntax**.

For e.g. I'd like to find the `@endif` for an `@if` statement in a large blade file or the `@endforeach` for the `@foreach` loop etc.

See here how the **opening HTML tag** is **highlighted with the closing one**:

[image]

I've been looking around but have not found anything.

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241022/vscode-formatting-using-laravel-blade-formatter-and-php-intelephense/71242517#71242517 helpful

Comment: @Hermi does my latest update solve the issue ?

Comment: I am afraid it didn't solve the issue, blade components would have massively helped but unfortunately in my case, it's not an option. Also, thanks for the tip on those themes.

Comment: I'll still keep an eye out and update this question if I find anything that could be used to highlight opening/closing **blade syntax** `(IF/ENDIF - FOREACH/ENDFOREACH)`.

Answer (score 2):

## For HTML opening and closing tags

Use [Highlight Matching Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)
[image]

---

## For Blade directives

The ultimate solution that I've found is installing [Blade Syntax for PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=namesmt.blade-php) and [Blade Color](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=namesmt.blade-color) extensions which are developed by the same person.

But it didn't work for me as shown on its preview.

The project seems to be abandoned for now since the last update was in June 2021 ...

---

However a **good theme** with **proper formatting** can save the day:

**Solarized Dark**
[image]

**Tomorrow Night Blue**
[image]

**Monokai Dimmed**
[image]

**Destroy your eyes**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @medilies I already switched to themes that highlight blade syntax and it did help a little but sometimes I work on some large files and I get lost so easily hence I'm looking for something that matches blade tags.

Still no luck with this though. will keep looking and update here if anything.

Comment: @Hemi For now I recommend using **Blade-components**. That would make your code shorter as it should be + reusable. I'll update my answer if I discover another solution :)

Comment: Thanks, @medilies,  I found the  Blade Syntax for PHP works fine for me!  I like the rest of my colors.