# how to highlight Laravel Blade directives inside script tags with vscode?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

If I have a basic component with inline scripts like this

**LARAVEL PHP COMPONENT**

```
@if(true)
    <div class="button-comp"></button>
@endif

<script>
@if(true)
    document.querySelector('.button-comp').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e) );
@endif
</script>
```

the Blade if directives inside the script tags, will not highlight in a correct way:

[image]

is there any settings that I'm missing in my vscodes's laravel extensions?

```
Laravel Extra Intellisense
Laravel Blade Snippets
```

**UPDATE**
this is related to LARAVEL BLADE SNIPPETS extension, there are other users with the same issue https://github.com/onecentlin/laravel-blade-snippets-vscode/issues/127. As @TimLewis wrotes in the comments, only solution is to assign the PHP variable to a JS variable, and use a JS if statement,in this way I can avoid the use of blade directives.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241022/vscode-formatting-using-laravel-blade-formatter-and-php-intelephense/71242517#71242517

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71341266/9636400

Comment: you can also use before and after script tag.

Comment: @JSTECH yes but I need those inside in example for declaring a var inside a function

Comment: Sound like funny. why don't you use JS if statement

Comment: @JSTECH from my POV your questions sounds funny too, how can you pass data from PHP to JS? Let's say that you are trying to pass a token that is generated on server side to an AJAX call. Of course I can put the token in an hidden field an got the value directly in my frontend, but why to write more code?

Comment: @silvered.dragon I am not familar to AJAX concept what you are trying to say, but there is some trick to pass PHP variable or data to JS in laravel.

Comment: Have you tried placing `<script>` and `</script>` _inside_ the `@if ... @endif`?

Comment: @brombeer yes this works, but I need the tags inside for passing variables from php to js in my blade

Comment: I think you're going to have to pick the "lesser of two evils" here; you can have the weird highlighting of the `@if(...)` and `@endif` inside a `<script>` element of a `.blade.php` file, or you can set a PHP variable via a `data-` attribute, and use a `JS` if statement. Or, assign the PHP variable to a JS variable, and use a `JS` if statement, like `const whatever = '{{ $whatever }}';` (with or without `'`, depending on the datatype; `true` was a really bad example here), then `if (whatever) { ... }`. I get what you're trying to do, but it _is_ language mixing, and VSCode may not handle that.

Comment: @TimLewis yes the true statement is a bad example, anyway this is not related to vscode but to the very well know used extension `laravel blade snippets` you can check here that there is a know unfixed issue `https://github.com/onecentlin/laravel-blade-snippets-vscode/issues/127`.  I know that mixing PHP and JS is not a good practice, but if you are developing reusable big components with inline JS, it is very helpfull (at least for me) to not write extra JS stuffs if I can grab everything with a blade directive.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that plugin, but it is still a VSCode issue, since that is an extension for VSCode  And again, I know what you're trying to do; I use that approach often too (it's helpful for other things, like not having blocks of JS code in your `.js` files unless they're needed, etc.). What I'm trying to say is that it's not likely anyone on Stackoverflow can help with this; the plugin would need an update (we can't do that), or you'll need to use an alternative solution (as we're suggesting); you'll have to pick one of those solutions (but obviously one _isn't_ a solution right now).

Comment: @TimLewis you are absolutely right but, at the beginning, I was thinking that it was me missing something about inline js in a blade engine (in my head I always think that an extension, used by millions of users, is designed for every situation, but I forget that behind there are always people made of meat). Anyway I think I will live with this until something better comes out, if it comes.